# How to change value of textbox based ona value of combobox in a userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change values of textbox according to values of combobox. As I'm  newcomer in VBA and VBA UserForm I can't fix it myself

```
Private Sub tbxDivision_Change()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks("...").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    If cboResponsible.value = "ENGINEERS" Then
        txtDivision.Value = ws.Cells("A7")
    Elseif ...

    End if
End sub
```

This is the code that I've tryed to run. I've tried to built this code to textbox body but I think that it's wrong. There is already a macro in combo box, so I don't now how to fix it. Name of textbox is txtDivision and combobox is cboResponsible

Comment: what's the name of textbox ? why txt.Division ?

Comment: Where is your issue? What exactly is your question? What is not working? Any errors (If so which and where)? • Note that `txt.Division` is no valid name for a textbox there are no dots allowed in textbox names. Also `Cells()` is not taking a range name like `Range("A7")` but row/column numbers like `Cells(row, column)`.

Comment: You should put this code in `cboResponsible_Change` not `tbxDivision_Change` and your textbox is `tbxDivision` not `txt.Division`. Be more precise and have a look twice at your code.